# Implement Next-Auth to consume protected routes of custom Laravel Backend

Tags: laravel, next.js, laravel-passport, next-auth

I'm very new to Next-Auth.

#### Here's my tech stack:

- [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) as the Backend
- [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) for OAuth
- Next.js 13 (`App Directory`)
- Next-Auth `4.18.8`

#### What I'm trying to achieve?

I already have the backend developed in `Laravel`, I wan to use `Next.js` just for serving to the end user.
I've configured custom OAuth provider in `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts` like this:

```js
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    {
      id: "I4T",
      name: "I4T",
      type: "oauth",
      authorization: {
        url: `${process.env.I4T_BACKEND_URL}/oauth/authorize`,
        params: { scope: "" }
      },
      token: `${process.env.I4T_BACKEND_URL}/oauth/token`,
      userinfo: `${process.env.I4T_BACKEND_URL}/api/user`,
      clientId: process.env.I4T_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.I4T_CLIENT_SECRET,
      profile: (profile) => {
        return profile
      },
      
    }
  ],
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

It works as expected.

But I also want to call any subsequent protected API routes (*e.g: perform some CRUD operations etc..*) of the Laravel backend from the Next.js application (both `Client components` and `Server components`) and for example if any of the call returns `Unauthorized` I want the Next.js application to be logged out.

I'm not sure how to achieve the same in most secure way, read many articles/tutorials but all of them ends at just setting up custom OAuth provider. :(

Any help is much appricated :)

Comment: any luck with it?

Comment: @nicolasDevDes Unfortunately no, please let us know if you found any resource in this topic?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth No :( please let us know if you find something.